# .htaccess RewriteEngine On not working in current server (ionos), but proved to be working with others

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

Below code is correct but not working

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ index.php?pi=$1 [NC,L]
```

this code is under the folder of
`https://www.ecommercelocal.com.au/accountants/nsw-state/`
designed to removed file index.php and the pagination ugly URL and make seo friendly pages in order to change the below page (URL)

`https://www.ecommercelocal.com.au/accountants/nsw-state/index.php?pi=2`

to
`https://www.ecommercelocal.com.au/accountants/nsw-state/2/`

However, it is not working anymore after migration to ionos.  any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve a "ticket" with IONOS?

Comment: Many thanks,  Not yet, still going through level 2 and higher.

Comment: the ticket came up with solution but not viable. ##   RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /accountants/nsw-state
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?pi=$1 [NC,L]    ## because I have to change about 19200 files.